# Robot doesn't Follow its path and particle cloud spreads out

Tags: navigation, mapping, path, stack, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone,

Has anyone had an experience with the robot following the path and going off it from time to time? It causes my robot to run into the walls and Im struggling with finding the solution to this problem. I should also mention that the robot doesn't see the obstacles and I don't know how to go out this.

Kind regards,
Maciej

With the reply to the comment I am posting all my config files below, if code is needed, this will be provided too.

Launch file:

```
    <launch>

 <node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl" output="screen">

  <param name="base_frame" value = "base_link"/>
  <param name="fixed_frame" value = "map"/>
  <param name="use_cloud_input" value="true"/>
  <param name="use_laser_input" value="true"/>
  <param name="publish_tf" value="true"/>
  <param name="publish_odom" value="true"/>
  <param name="use_odom" value="false"/>
  <param name="use_imu" value="false"/>
  <param name="use_alpha_beta" value="true"/>
  <param name="max_iterations" value="10"/>

</node>

<node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="/home/maciejm/catkin_ws/src/map1.yaml"/>


  <node pkg="my_sensor" type="my_sensor" name="my_sensor" output="screen">
    <param name="sensor_param" value="param_value" />
  </node>

  <node pkg="my_sensor" type="laser_cloud" name="laser_cloud" output="screen">
    <param name="sensor_param" value="param_value" />
  </node>

  <node pkg="robot_setup_tf" type="my_odom" name="my_odom" output="screen">
    <param name="odom_param" value="param_value" />
  </node>

  <node pkg="robot_setup_tf" type="tf_broadcaster" name="broadcaster" output="screen">
    <param name="broadcaster" value="param_value" />
  </node>

  <node pkg="robot_setup_tf" type="tf_listener" name="listener" output="screen">
    <param name="listener" value="param_value" />
  </node>

<node pkg="robot_setup_tf" type="pose_publisher" name="pose_publisher" output="screen">
    <param name="pose_publisher" value="param_value" />
  </node>
<node pkg="robot_setup_tf" type="base_controller" name="base_controller" output="screen">
    <param name="base_controller" value="param_value" />
  </node>

  <node type="laser_scan_assembler" pkg="laser_assembler" name="my_assembler">
    <remap from="scan" to="tilt_scan"/>
    <param name="max_scans" type="int" value="400" />
    <param name="fixed_frame" type="string" value="base_link" />
  </node>

  <node type="point_cloud_assembler" pkg="laser_assembler" name="my_assembler2">
    <remap from="cloud" to="my_cloud_in"/>
    <param name="max_clouds" type="int" value="400" />
    <param name="fixed_frame" type="string" value="base_link" />
  </node>

  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot_name_2dnav)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot_name_2dnav)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot_name_2dnav)/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot_name_2dnav)/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot_name_2dnav)/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
    
  </node>

<node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" output="screen">
    <param name="rviz" value="param_value" />
  </node>
  
</launch>
```

Base local planner:

```
TrajectoryPlannerROS:
  max_vel_x: 0.25
  min_vel_x: 0.1
  max_vel_theta: 1.0
  min_in_place_vel_theta: 0.4

  acc_lim_theta: 10.0
  acc_lim_x: 10.0
  acc_lim_y: 10.0

  holonomic_robot: false
  meter_scoring: true
```

Global costmap:

```
global_costmap:
  global_frame: /map
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 5.0
  static_map: true
```

Local costmap:

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: /odom
  robot_base_frame: /base_link
  update_frequency: 5.0
  publish_frequency: 5.0
  static_map: true
  rolling_window: true
  /*width: 6.0
  /*height: 6.0
  resolution: 0.05
  obstacles: 5.0
```

Costmap common:

```
obstacle_range: 1.5
raytrace_range: 1.5
#robot_radius: 0.1
inflation_radius: 0.5
transform_tolerance: 0.3
footprint: [ [0.25, 0.25], [-0.25, 0.25],[-0.25, -0.25], [0.25, -0.25], [0.35,0.0] ]
observation_sources: my_sensor laser_cloud

laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: my_sensor, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true}

point_cloud_sensor: {sensor_frame: laser_cloud, data_type: PointCloud, topic: topic_name, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

I hope that this helps with solving my problem.

Also with regards to screenshots, it seems that the local costmap doens't update and gets depleted as time goes:
[image description http://snag.gy/h3jeN.jpg](http://snag.gy/h3jeN.jpg)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227202/robot-doesn%27t-follow-its-path-and-particle-cloud-spreads-out/) by [maciejm](https://answers.ros.org/users/25237/maciejm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2016-02-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2016-02-21**:
You should provide more information like packages, launch files, configuration files, parameters you use, and any console outputs (warnings, errors, etc), and screenshots if applicable.

**Comment by [maciejm](https://answers.ros.org/users/25237/maciejm/) on 2016-02-21**:
Here you go Akif, I hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At first, it seems like you have a problem with observation sources configuration;

```
observation_sources: my_sensor laser_cloud

laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: my_sensor, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true}

point_cloud_sensor: {sensor_frame: laser_cloud, data_type: PointCloud, topic: topic_name, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

You define your sources as `my_sensor` and `laser_cloud` but you name them as `laser_scan_sensor` and `point_cloud_sensor` . Therefore try changing to this;

```
observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor point_cloud_sensor
        
laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: my_sensor, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
      
point_cloud_sensor: {sensor_frame: laser_cloud, data_type: PointCloud, topic: topic_name, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [maciejm](https://answers.ros.org/users/25237/maciejm/) on 2016-02-21**:
I corrected it but the problem still persists... the local map doesn't update and sometimes flickers should I attach laser scanner and cloud code? is there any way to not use them and still get localisation?